# Cordova Diagnostic plugin does nothing

Tags: xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

This is my first cordova app and i'm trying to use the cordova.plugins.diagnostic plugin. I have it installed correctly i believe. On device ready I can alert that

```
alert(cordova.plugins.diagnostic != null) // returns true

// Appears to do nothing, i get no alerts
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
    alert(enabled)
}, function(){
    alert("ERROR");
});
```

I assume my error is with how i am running the app. I build the app via

```
cordova build ios
```

Then I run the build via xCode 9.4 to a local iPhone X

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue! Originally, when running

```
cordova build ios
```

I would receive and archive not found error, that i was essentially ignoring because it didnt seem to effect anything when built via xCode.

I resolved the error by running instead

```
cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Then, I can take the outputed .ipa file and install it onto my device via

```
Window > Devices and Simulators > {select device} > drag and drop ipa into app list
```

Running the app after this allowed for successfull response from isLocationEnabled!

I hope this answer helps someone else :D